# exporting pages from a pdf on windows

Tags: windows, pdf

I can't figure out how to extract a few pages from a pdf on windows.

- There is no option to do so in the idiotic default viewer
- I can print to an idiotic "XPS" format from which their is no option to export to pdf

Is there really no native way to do so on windows ??

Comment: what do you mean "on windows"? what viewer and what version of windows  are you using? normaly a viewer is just that: you can view files, not edit them...

Comment: it is also common sense to provide very simple feature like in macos preview. between full fledge editor, and viewer only, there are things you'd expect a 'viewer' to do.

Comment: i use windows 8 which raises another round of interrogations in itself. but since pdf was here forever i assumed (rightly apparently) that all windows of recent grade (>= XP) would play the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know to what you're refering in your first point but, according to the second point you can:

- Export to PDF from Office apps like MS Office, Libre Office or Open Office
- You can download and install PDF Printer (or CutePDF or any other software that works the same) that will behave in a same way that XPS printer works (the one you have encountered already) but will export anything you can print to PDF format

So... yes, there is no native way that MS Windows would provide.

Comment: I tried cutePDF and it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have any built-in tools to open PDF documents. In order to even view a PDF document, one must install Acrobat Reader. You can install third-party utilities that will allow you to do what you want to do, though:

1. Extracting text: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187250/pdf-text-extraction) was asked at Stack Overflow, but from personal experience, I've found that [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/) does a much better job at text extraction. Of course, if Command Line is your thing, FreeOCR may not cut it for you.
2. Creating a PDF: Like Battlefist said, you have many options for the second part of your question. [DoPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/), and [BullZip PDF](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) are two notable mentions.